# How do you set an Attributed Title Color for State in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm able to set the `attributedTitle` for a `UIControlState`, but how would I set the attributed title's color for a `UIControlState`?

Comment: In your title attributes dictionary: `NSForegroundColorAttributeName: someColor`

Comment: Right, that works fine, but that doesn't let me set the color based on the .Selected control state

Comment: use the setAttributedText for control state .... this shall do...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
// create the button
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

// set the attributed title for different states

// .Selected
let mySelectedAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here",
    attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.greenColor()])
button.setAttributedTitle(mySelectedAttributedTitle, forState: .Selected)

// .Normal
let myNormalAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here",
    attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()])
button.setAttributedTitle(myNormalAttributedTitle, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: @NatashaTheRobot can you please help me its not working in selected case here?

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 4 & 5**

```
    // create the button
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    
    // set the attributed title for different states
    
    // .Selected
    let mySelectedAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here",
                                                       attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.green])
    button.setAttributedTitle(mySelectedAttributedTitle, for: .selected)
    
    // .Normal
    let myNormalAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here",
                                                     attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue])
    
    
    button.setAttributedTitle(myNormalAttributedTitle, for: .normal)
```

Swift 3

```
// create the button
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

// set the attributed title for different states

// .Selected
let mySelectedAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here",
                                               attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.green])
button.setAttributedTitle(mySelectedAttributedTitle, for: .selected)

// .Normal
let myNormalAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here",
                                             attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue])


button.setAttributedTitle(myNormalAttributedTitle, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Hi @kuzdu I have used this code but its not working in selected case. can you please explain whole step ?

Comment: NSAttributedStringKey has been replaced with NSAttributedString.Key

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 functions to set the color and font.

```
class func setButtonTextColor( _ button:UIButton , color:UIColor ) {
    if let str = button.titleLabel?.attributedText {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString( attributedString: str  )
        attributedString.removeAttribute(.foregroundColor, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
        attributedString.addAttributes(
            [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : color],
            range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
        )
        button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
    }
}

class func setButtonTextFont( _ button:UIButton, font: UIFont) {
    if let str = button.titleLabel?.attributedText {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString( attributedString: str  )
        attributedString.removeAttribute(.font, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
        attributedString.addAttributes(
            [NSAttributedString.Key.font : font ],
            range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
        )
        button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
    }
}
```