# Swift how can I partially change UILabel's colour

Tags: swift, uilabel, calayer

[image]

I am designing an option bar on the navigation bar of my app, I want to achieve the same UI of that of the Music App, as you can see when the slider is sliding, the UILabel is partially changing its color, how does this be archived? Should I work on CALayer?

This is what I did so far, it's just not correct

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        
            self.optionBarSlider.frame = self.selectedButton.frame
        }) { _ in
            self.selectedButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with setting `attributedText` to change the color of the portion that you need

[How do you set an Attributed Title Color for State in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624890/how-do-you-set-an-attributed-title-color-for-state-in-swift/42484307)